# Can Sign Up via Supabase but user isn't taken to the next view

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, supabase, swiftui-navigationview

I am building my first iOS app with Supabase. I can create a user in the Database when the user clicks SignUp but the user is not taken to the next HomeView. The app does nothing and I see nothing in console.

Any suggestions as to how I can troubleshoot or solve the problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
import SwiftUI
import Supabase

struct SignUpView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = SignUpViewModel()
    @State private var activeNavigation: SignUpNavigation?
    @State private var email: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""
    @State private var confirmPassword: String = ""
    @State private var errorMessage: String = ""
    @Binding var isSignUpViewVisible: Bool
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text("Sign Up")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .padding(.bottom, 20)
                
                TextField("Email", text: $email)
                    .padding()
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .autocapitalization(.none)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                
                SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                    .padding()
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                
                SecureField("Confirm Password", text: $confirmPassword)
                    .padding()
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                
                if !errorMessage.isEmpty {
                    Text(errorMessage)
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .padding()
                }
                
                Button(action: signUp) {
                    Text("Sign Up")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .padding()
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 40)
                        .padding(.top, 20)
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: {
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }) {
                    Text("Already have an account? Log In")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .padding(.bottom, 10)
                }
                
                NavigationLink(value: activeNavigation, label: {
                    switch activeNavigation {
                    case .personalization:
                        PersonalizationView()
                    case .interviewAI:
                        InterviewAIView()
                    case .none:
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                })
                .opacity(0) // Hide the NavigationLink
            }
            .padding(.top, 60)
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        }
    
    
    
    private func signUp() {
        // Password validation before signUp
        if password != confirmPassword {
            errorMessage = "Passwords do not match."
            return
        }
        
        viewModel.signUp(email: email, password: password) { error in
            if let error = error {
                errorMessage = "Sign Up Error: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                print("Error during sign up: \(error.localizedDescription)") // Debug print
            } else {
                print("Sign up successful") // Debug print
                self.activeNavigation = .personalization
                print("Navigating to PersonalizationView") // Debug print
            }
        }
    }
}

enum SignUpNavigation: Identifiable {
    case personalization
    case interviewAI
    
    var id: Self { self }
}

struct SignUpView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SignUpView(isSignUpViewVisible: .constant(true))
    }
}
```

Here is the SignUpViewModel

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Supabase

class SignUpViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let supabaseURLString = "Bob Seger"
    let supabaseKeyString = "Bob Seger"
    let client: SupabaseClient

    init() {
        client = SupabaseClient(supabaseURL: URL(string: supabaseURLString)!, supabaseKey: supabaseKeyString)
    }

    func signUp(email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        Task {
            do {
                try await client.auth.signUp(email: email, password: password)
                completion(nil)
            } catch {
                completion(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For a `NavigationLink` to "work", you need a `NavigationStack` in your view hierarchy. Do you have that? Note, you don't have a `HomeView` in your code, did you mean `PersonalizationView()`?

Comment: Thank you. Many of my other links work. I'll try to mirror that functionality. I do mean PersonalizationView as I want the user to go there before the HomeView. Good eye. I appreciate it. I am not sure if I have a NavigationStack in my view hierarchy.